# is getDerivedStateFromProps called during Server-side rendering?

Tags: reactjs

In [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) they write:

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked after a component is instantiated
>   as well as when it receives new props.

Does **instantiated** means the same as mounted?

So I'm asking if

`import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';`

will call this hook.

Comment: The docs tell you this: "A component begins its life when it is instantiated. The constructor is called with the initial set of props. In this function, we perform any initialization logic and set the component's initial state."

Comment: So the answer is Yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough to actually test. Simply call ReactDOMServer.render... with a component that has a `getDerivedStateFromError` and an error path in it's render function.

The idea behind `getDerivedStateFromError` is that [it can be supported](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9lp0k3/new_lifecycle_method_getderivedstatefromerror/e79elpl) by the server side render pass.

It was added in [16.6.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1660-october-23-2018) and but it is not yet supported by the server side render code. The primary reason for adding this is to enable error handling in async server side rendering code.